# Дергаются ссылки при наведении только на Айфоне

Tags: html, css

Наблюдаю неприятный эффект на айфонах - прыгают ссылки. При загрузке блок с ссылками быстро и плавно увеличивается, затем уменьшается до заданных в CSS размеров. Если пальцем водить по этим ссылкам, у блока происходят конвульсии - ссылки увеличиваются и уменьшаются. Происходит это только в одном блоке с ссылками.

Ни на одном устройстве больше эта проблема не воспроизводится (десктоп, планшет Эппл, телефоны на Андроиде).

В чем может быть причина? Как с этим справиться?

Привожу код, но он самый обычный:

HTML

```
<div>
<a href="tel:+7644664">+7 (64) 46-64</a>
<br>
<a href="tel:+7644664">+7 (64) 46-64</a>
<br>
<a href="tel:+7644664">+7 (64) 46-64</a>
<br>
<a href="tel:+7644664">+7 (64) 46-64</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  line-height: 1.5;
  }
div a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #000;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
          transition: all .4s ease;
  }
div a:hover {
  color: #25c019;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #25c019;
  }
```

Comment: вместо border можно попробовать использовать box-shadow, или абсолютный псевдо элемент, который будет проявляться при наведении.

Answer (score 1):

Решение наконец-то было найдено. Проблема оказалось в банальном - невнимательность.

Может кому-то мой ответ будет полезен, когда будете сталкиваться с "необъяснимым" поведением элементов на сайте.

В приведенном коде я упустила два важных момента (когда писала, не обратила внимание на их важность) - **наличие медиазапроса** и присутствие на странице второго блока с ссылками. Классы у блоков разные, но **одинаковый id**, к которому обращались в медизапросах, увеличивая размер шрифта.

Я не поняла почему только Айфон так чутко реагировал на этот сомнительный ход, в любом случае мне это помогло все-таки найти косяк и исправить, **убрав font-size, прописанный к id** и более верно прописать размер шрифтов у разных блоков на мобильном.

Надеюсь, что мой ход мыслей поможет еще кому-нибудь :)

Comment: Не правильно ставить одинаковые ID html элементам.
Одинаковыми могут быть только классы, для того и нужны, ID все должны быть уникальными. Такие уж правила.
Вообще гугл хром, например, будет ругаться в консоли на идентичные ID найденные на одной странице.
Валидаторы, конечно, тоже не пропустят такие html документы.

Comment: а может ли быть одинаковый ID у элементов на странице, которые вызывают, например, одно и тоже всплывающее окно с одинаковым содержимым?